# A proof of fraction inequality by induction

Tags: inequality, induction, contest-math

Prove that $$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n\le\frac{a^{n}+b^{n}}{2}$$ I have checked the base case and assumed the inequality is valid and continued like this $$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n+1}\le\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}\Rightarrow \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\le\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}$$ Multiplying by $2$ I got $$\frac{(a+b)^{n+1}}{2^n}\le a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}$$ and I don't know how to continue from here. I've also tried using the binomial theorem to get something different but couldn't get anything useful.

Comment: can you please double check the exponents? You had incoherent exponents

Comment: Are there conditions on $a,b$? I'm getting that the inequality doesn't hold for $n=1$ if $a=b=0.5$.

Comment: $a,b>0$ and $n\ge2$ Sorry!

Comment: @RSerrao if you are referring to use of $n+1$ instead of $n$ in the exponent that's because I'm trying to prove the inequality for $n+1$ assuming it holds for $n$

Comment: @ahra nope, I was referring to the fact that in the first line you had $n+1$ on the RHS.

Comment: @RSerrao oh, it was already edited so I didn't catch it the first time, thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work:

$\left( \dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n+1}=\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^n\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)$

$ \hspace{2.6  cm}\leq \dfrac{a^n+b^n}{2}\cdot \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)$

$\hspace{2.6 cm} = \dfrac{a^{n+1}+a^nb+ab^n+b^{n+1}}{4}$

Now write what you want to obtain and subtract extras:

$\hspace{2.6 cm} = \dfrac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}-\dfrac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{4}+\dfrac{a^nb+ab^n}{4}$

$\hspace{2.6cm} = \dfrac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}-\left(\dfrac{a^{n+1}-a^nb-ab^n-b^{n+1}}{4}\right)$

$\hspace{2.6cm} = \dfrac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}-\left(\dfrac{a^{n}(a-b)-b^n(a-b)}{4}\right)$

$\hspace{2.6cm} = \dfrac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}-\dfrac{(a-b)(a^n-b^n)}{4}=*$

No matter if $a\geq b$ or $b> a$ expression $ \dfrac{(a-b)(a^n-b^n)}{4}$ is positive. So, in conclusion:

$\hspace{2.6cm}*\leq \dfrac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}$

Comment: @ahra It's exactly my proof, which was posted before I don't understand you.

Comment: Your proof is simply incomplete and doesn't show why the statement is valid on the most fundamental level.

Comment: @ahra I don't agree with you! See please my post and my comments again.

Answer (score 2):

It's just $$\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}\geq\frac{a+b}{2}\cdot\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n+1},$$
here the left inequality it's $(a^n-b^n)(a-b)\geq0$, which is obvious and

the right inequality it's a hypothesis of the induction.

Comment: Well, that might be obvious to you, but it is not to me. Can you prove that statement by induction?

Comment: @ahra the right inequality it's a hypothesis and we need to prove that $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n+1}$ which is done by induction, which you wish.

Comment: @ahra If you say about left inequality so see my proof in my post.